# Order of intersection of two subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $H$, $K$ be subgroups of $G$. In general, $\vert H \cap K \vert$ is a common divisor of $\vert H \vert$ and $\vert K \vert$. When $G$ is a cyclic group, the order of $H \cap K$ is $\gcd(\vert H \vert, \vert K \vert)$. When it is not cyclic, the same rule does not apply. What if one subgroup is cyclic and the other is noncyclic? Is there a way to know the exact order like that of two cyclic subgroups?

Comment: I'm afraid the thing you know is not true... It is not the case that if $H$ and $K$ are cyclic then $|H\cap K|={\rm gcd}(|H|,|K|)$, the most obvious example being $G=C_2\times C_2$ with generating set $\{x,y\}$, $H=\langle x\rangle$ and $K=\langle y\rangle$, then $|H|=|K|=2$ but $|H\cap K|=1$. $|H\cap K|={\rm gcd}(|H|,|K|)$ does however hold if $G$ is cyclic.

Comment: This question only makes sense when $G$ is finite.

Comment: Yes, $G$ is of finite order.

Comment: @user161872: In general $|H K|\cdot |H\cap K| = |H|\cdot |K|$.